# Typescript: declaring typings on a file level, not a data structure

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I don't believe this is possible with Typescript but thought I'd ask anyway.

I'm trying to enforce a particular arrangement of *exports* from a TS file. It's for a plugin-based script where plugins may or may not export certain functionality, but they *must* export certain other things. I'd like to type the *exports* from a single file within each bundle.

I realize I could group everything into a single data structure within the plugins and type that, but by doing that I'd lose the benefits of tree shaking in my bundling tool.

Here's an example.

Say my plugins:

- *must* export a `generate` function (which for the sake of illustration could be massive - several MBs)
- *must* export a `config` object of a particular type, which defines metadata about the plugin.
- can *optionally* export a `getOtherInfo` function.
- any other exports are invalid.

I can type this easily by grouping it all into an object & typing that, but then any time I want to import just the `config` object, I end up getting the massive `generate` method - which I don't want in my bundle.

But I don't see a way to declare typings on the file-level like I need. Any ideas?